# How to use Shared Preference for save a Position Android?

Tags: android

I want to save in store a position in my shared preferences, and can edit it, and open it when app starts, thanks, i have this:

```
//load shared preferecnes
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
                                                           Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//note: here idk how to read the last value of position saved
//Log.v("lastposition", sharedPreferences );

// on edit preferences and save
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("position", New LatLang(30,40) );
editor.commit();
```

Thanks everyone :)

---

LAST EDIT CHANGES:

```
//load shared preferecnes
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(this,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// --> HERE IDK HOT LOAD LAST POSITIONS SAVED

// on edit preferences and save
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putDouble("position_lat", 30d );
editor.putDouble("position_lon", 40d);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem? Saving a preference, or loading it?

Comment: You can't store anything you want into the Preferences. You have to split your `LatLong` Object into Strings, int etc.

Comment: now i can save it using double, but now my problem is load it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sharedPreferences.getString("position", new LatLng(30,40).toString());
```

if your application has no information saved at "position", it needs to load a default value instead. Here it is LatLng(30,40). 
But you can not save complex objects such as LatLng. What you can do instead, is saving/loading latitude and longitude values:

```
//load shared preferecnes
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(this,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//note: here you load the saved latitude and longitude values into the variable with name "loaded_position":

LatLng loaded_position = new LatLng(0,0);
loaded_position.latitude= sharedpreferences.getFloat("position_lat", 15f);
loaded_position.longitude = sharedpreferences.getFloat("position_lon", 15f);
Log.v("lastposition", "loaded position: ("+loaded_position.latitude+","+loaded_position.longitude+")" );

// on edit preferences, save the LatLng Object:
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(30f,40f);
editor.putFloat("position_lat", (float) currentPosition.latitude );
editor.putFloat("position_lon", (float) currentPosition.longitude);
editor.commit();
```

This code, loads your by editor saved (30,40) into loaded_position. It should load 15,15 instead on your first start of the application, because 30,40 is not saved at that first start in your sharedPreferences.

Comment: then for read it should be -> sharedPreferences.getString("position_lat" ); ? or how? thanks

Comment: yes, yes , i mean,getDouble, but what have i put in the field 'defaultvalue'??? thanks

Comment: defaultvalue is the value, that gets loaded, when there is nothing found in your sharedpreferences at the key "position_lat". so use any value just like in the answer the 15d

Comment: i cant use get double, only get float, what should I do? :S thanks

Comment: You are right, you actually can not save doubles into the sharedPreferences. I changed the code for loading/saving latitude/longitude as floats.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this page please:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html